# Updates in Java SE 5 Logging

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Are there any significant updates in the Logging facility provided by Java SE 5 from J2SE 1.4?

Comment: If you are upgrading I would upgrade to a version of Java which has been end-of-life for more than a year.  Consider upgrading to Java 6. Java 7 will be out in the next few months, but you might even consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html):

> Monitoring and management API for the
> logging facility
>
> The new
> java.util.logging.LoggingMXBean
> interface is the management interface
> for the logging facility.

Comment: Are these capabilities provided in Log4J and Logback as well? I want to decide on which framework to use.

Comment: @TheLameProgrammer: I'm not sure about that.

Comment: and for log4j http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jmx/package-summary.html